# Tiles over Linonium

Tags: tile

I plan to install Porcelin tiles over Linonium, The issue is with the dishwasher clearance. I was told not to lay tiles under the dishwasher. My worry is, how the dishwasher will be taken out once the tiles are laid. The current height of the counter is 34 1/2 inch and dish washer needs 34 inch minimum.

I saw some other post where it was suggested to remove the adjuster nut from the feet in order to get the dishwasher in.

Any guidance is appreciated.

Answer (score 1):

Most dishwashers have adjustable feet that allow you to position them properly in the space.

Just be sure you have enough clearance so that you can lower the height enough to get the dishwasher out even with the tiles installed.

BTW - I'm not sure I'd lay tile over vinyl flooring (I assume it's vinyl and you're just calling it linoleum) as you might have difficulty with the setting compound adhering.  Be sure whatever product you use specifies that it will work on that base.  Check with the product manufacturer if it's unclear.

Comment: Whatever it is (sheet vinyl or linoleum) it's not a suitable substrate for porcelain tile, IMHO.

Comment: @Ecnerwal Agreed but some people do things like that anyway.  I'd be afraid it would come loose over time.

Answer (score 0):

I did a similar project.  Only instead of laying the tiles directly over the sheet vinyl, I put down a layer a cement backer board, then the tiles.  This raised the who floor up ~3/4".  I tiled under the dishwasher (and the stove & refrigerator) also.  In order to provide the headroom for the dishwasher, I shimmed the counter up 3/4" with some 1x2's.  The counter was being replaced anyway, so I did not have to worry about damaging the existing counter.  The only thing I lost in this process was about 3/4" height above the surface of the new counter to the bottom of the wall cabinets.

[image]

Comment: The contractor will be screwing cement boards on top of the linoleum and will lay the tile on that. this will increase the heiight by approx 3/4" . the counter height is 34 1/2" and dishwasher is 34". 

I was told that if I dont have tiles under the dishwasher, I can remove the front adjustable feet and slide the dishwasher in and out. 
Please advise if this is doable.

Comment: Without knowing the particulars of your dishwasher, I can't say for sure.  Here's something you might consider.  Get a small piece of 3/4" plywood and nail it down in front of the dishwasher opening - basically mocking up the new height of the floor.  Then see what it takes to get your dishwasher in and out.

Comment: with the counter top in place there may not be enough room to remove the front feet.